# unable to create a relationship with sequelize in postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

So i wish to create the following 2 tables : `user` and `user_address` and have a 1:many relationship among them, i.e a user can have multiple addresses. I followed the sequelize docs and ran the `.belongsTo` and `hasMany` on the models of these 2 tables, but i can't seem to query them when i request for a all users with `include=[{model:'user_address'}]` filter. I wanted to create a scalable system, so i used a somewhat modular approach.

1. The tables are defined in different files as js objects:

```js
//user.js
const { DataTypes} = require('sequelize');

const name = "user"
const model ={
    email :     {type:DataTypes.STRING,         allowNull:false,unique:true},
    password :  {type:DataTypes.STRING(16),     allowNull:false},

    phone :     {type:DataTypes.STRING(20),     allowNull:true},
    name :      {type:DataTypes.STRING(50),     allowNull:true},
    birthday :  {type:DataTypes.STRING(50),     allowNull:true},
}
const initConfig = {freezeTableName: true}

const getInstance = (email, pwd, phone = null, name = null, dob = null)=>{
    return {email: email, password: pwd, phone: phone, name: name, birthday: dob}
}
module.exports = {
    name:name,
    model:model,
    config:initConfig,
    getInstance:getInstance
}
```

```js
//user_address.js
const {DataTypes} = require("sequelize");
const name = "user_address"
const model = {
    address :                   {type:DataTypes.STRING,         allowNull:false},
    zipcode :                   {type:DataTypes.INTEGER,        allowNull:false},
    is_main_address :           {type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,        allowNull:false, default:false},

    address_alias :             {type:DataTypes.STRING,         allowNull:true},
    address_phone_number :      {type:DataTypes.STRING,         allowNull:true},
    city :                      {type:DataTypes.STRING,         allowNull:true},

}
//  user_id :  {type:DataTypes.INTEGER,       allowNull:true, references: {model: 'user', key: 'id',},}
const config = {
    freezeTableName: true
}
module.exports = {
    name:name,
    model:model,
    config:config,
    getInstance:()=>{},
}
```

then we have this ModelKeys.js class that provides an easy access to these model schemas:

```js
const user = require("./user");
const note = require("./note");
const user_address = require('./user_addresses')
module.exports = {
    ModelNames:{
        USER : user,
        USER_ADDRESS: user_address,
        NOTE: note,
    }
}
```

then we have this init db class that is supposed to initialise db, define models and run associations on them

```js
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');
const {db_creds} = require("../.secrets/db_secrets");
const {ModelNames} = require("./models/model_keys");
const {logDB} = require("../a_commons/logutils");
let db = undefined
async function initTables() {
    // create tables
    Object.keys(ModelNames).forEach(key=>{
        let model = ModelNames[key]
        try {
            logDB("initialising MODEL=",model==null? "null": `{js_obj : ${model.name}}`)
            db.define(model.name,model.model,model.config)
            logDB(`model created successfully : ${model.name}` )

        }
        catch (e) {logError(e)}
    })

    //sync with dbms
    logDB("initialising sync with dbms server...")
    await db.sync()
    logDB("models synced successfully")

}

function validateTables() {
    logDB("all tables are created.","tables=",db.models)
}


async function runAssociations(){
    //create associations
    logDB("init associations")
    let userTable = db.models[ModelNames.USER.name]
    let userAddressTable = db.models[ModelNames.USER_ADDRESS.name]

    await userTable.hasMany(userAddressTable)
    await userAddressTable.belongsTo(userTable)
    logDB("associations created successfully")

    //sync with dbms
    logDB("initialising sync with dbms server...")
    await db.sync()
    logDB("models synced successfully")

}



module.exports = {
    MyDatabase:{
        initDB : async () => {
            db = new Sequelize(db_creds)
            await db
                .authenticate()
                .then(_ => logDB('Connection established successfully.'))
                .then(_ => initTables())
                .then(_ => validateTables())
                .then(async _ => (await runAssociations()))
                .catch(error => logError('Something went wrong', error))

        },
        getDB: ()=> {
            // only useful once initDB is called
            return db;
        },
        getTable : (modelName) => {
            // only useful once initDB is called
            return db.models[modelName]
        }

    }
}
```

if you notice, i did not created any identifier primary keys for my tables but since sequelize automatically generates `id` key, i was expecting the tables to get created successfully, which they do. during `runAssociations()` , function, i was also not sure, if it would work since the tables have already been created, and neither table has any reference to them, but i expected this to work.

this whole file runs when someone calls `MyDatabase.initDB()` and it runs without any errors.

therefore i further created a `user_repo.js` which looks like this :

```js
const {MyDatabase} = require("./init_db");
const {ModelNames} = require("./models/model_keys");
const {logRepo} = require("../a_commons/logutils");


let userTable = null


module.exports = {
    UserRepo: {
        initDatabase: async () => {await MyDatabase.initDB()},
        init: () => {
            userTable = MyDatabase.getTable(ModelNames.USER.name)
            logRepo("table initialised. table=",userTable.name)
        },
        createUser: async (user) => {
            await userTable
                .create(user)
                .then(it => logRepo("user build successfully!", it.toJSON()))
        },
        getAllUsers: async () => {
            let users = await userTable.findAll({include:[{model:MyDatabase.getTable(ModelNames.USER_ADDRESS.name)}]})
            logRepo("available users = ", users.map(it=>it.email))
            return users
        },
        getSingleUser: async (email) =>{
            return await userTable.findOne(
                {where: {email: email}, include:[{model:MyDatabase.getTable(ModelNames.USER_ADDRESS)}]},

            )
        }
    }
}
```

however, when i run these lines:

```js
const {UserRepo} = require("./user_repo");
const {ModelNames} = require("./models/model_keys");
async function x(){
    let repo = UserRepo
    await repo.initDatabase()
    await repo.init()
    await repo.createUser(ModelNames.USER.getInstance("ansh@12345.com","12345678"))
    await repo.getAllUsers()
}
x()
```

1st few lines run perfectly, but for `getAllUsers()` line ,i get this error :

```css
 Executing (default): SELECT "user"."id", "user"."email", "user"."password", "user"."phone", "user"."name", "user"."birthday", "user"."createdAt", "user"."updatedAt", "user_addresses"."id" AS "user_addresses.id", "user_addresses"."address" AS "user_addresses.address", "user_addresses"."zipcode" AS "user_addresses.zipcode", "user_addresses"."is_main_address" AS "user_addresses.is_main_address", "user_addresses"."address_alias" AS "user_addresses.address_alias", "user_addresses"."address_phone_number" AS "user_addresses.address_phone_number", "user_addresses"."city" AS "user_addresses.city", "user_addresses"."createdAt" AS "user_addresses.createdAt", "user_addresses"."updatedAt" AS "user_addresses.updatedAt", "user_addresses"."userId" AS "user_addresses.userId" FROM "user" AS "user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_address" AS "user_addresses" ON "user"."id" = "user_addresses"."userId";
node:internal/process/promises:265
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error
    at Query.run (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:50:25)
    at /Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:314:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async PostgresQueryInterface.select (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:407:12)
    at async Function.findAll (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1134:21)
    at async Object.getAllUsers (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/db/user_repo.js:22:25)
    at async x (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/db/test_io.js:101:5) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: column user_addresses.userId does not exist
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 120,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42703',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: '839',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'parse_relation.c',
    line: '3643',
    routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
    sql: 'SELECT "user"."id", "user"."email", "user"."password", "user"."phone", "user"."name", "user"."birthday", "user"."createdAt", "user"."updatedAt", "user_addresses"."id" AS "user_addresses.id", "user_addresses"."address" AS "user_addresses.address", "user_addresses"."zipcode" AS "user_addresses.zipcode", "user_addresses"."is_main_address" AS "user_addresses.is_main_address", "user_addresses"."address_alias" AS "user_addresses.address_alias", "user_addresses"."address_phone_number" AS "user_addresses.address_phone_number", "user_addresses"."city" AS "user_addresses.city", "user_addresses"."createdAt" AS "user_addresses.createdAt", "user_addresses"."updatedAt" AS "user_addresses.updatedAt", "user_addresses"."userId" AS "user_addresses.userId" FROM "user" AS "user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_address" AS "user_addresses" ON "user"."id" = "user_addresses"."userId";',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  original: error: column user_addresses.userId does not exist
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/anshsachdeva/Downloads/f1_self/f4_web/f4_web_individual_gits/ecommerce/sequalize_tests/notes_db/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 120,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42703',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: '839',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'parse_relation.c',
    line: '3643',
    routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
    sql: 'SELECT "user"."id", "user"."email", "user"."password", "user"."phone", "user"."name", "user"."birthday", "user"."createdAt", "user"."updatedAt", "user_addresses"."id" AS "user_addresses.id", "user_addresses"."address" AS "user_addresses.address", "user_addresses"."zipcode" AS "user_addresses.zipcode", "user_addresses"."is_main_address" AS "user_addresses.is_main_address", "user_addresses"."address_alias" AS "user_addresses.address_alias", "user_addresses"."address_phone_number" AS "user_addresses.address_phone_number", "user_addresses"."city" AS "user_addresses.city", "user_addresses"."createdAt" AS "user_addresses.createdAt", "user_addresses"."updatedAt" AS "user_addresses.updatedAt", "user_addresses"."userId" AS "user_addresses.userId" FROM "user" AS "user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_address" AS "user_addresses" ON "user"."id" = "user_addresses"."userId";',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: 'SELECT "user"."id", "user"."email", "user"."password", "user"."phone", "user"."name", "user"."birthday", "user"."createdAt", "user"."updatedAt", "user_addresses"."id" AS "user_addresses.id", "user_addresses"."address" AS "user_addresses.address", "user_addresses"."zipcode" AS "user_addresses.zipcode", "user_addresses"."is_main_address" AS "user_addresses.is_main_address", "user_addresses"."address_alias" AS "user_addresses.address_alias", "user_addresses"."address_phone_number" AS "user_addresses.address_phone_number", "user_addresses"."city" AS "user_addresses.city", "user_addresses"."createdAt" AS "user_addresses.createdAt", "user_addresses"."updatedAt" AS "user_addresses.updatedAt", "user_addresses"."userId" AS "user_addresses.userId" FROM "user" AS "user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_address" AS "user_addresses" ON "user"."id" = "user_addresses"."userId";',
  parameters: {}
}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register all models and all their associations **before** calling `sync` because `hasMany/belongsTo` only registers associations inside Sequelize models do nothing in DB. Its the responsibility of `sync` to create the whole structure taking into account all registered models and associations.

```js
           await db
                .authenticate()
                .then(_ => logDB('Connection established successfully.'))
                .then(_ => runAssociations())
                .then(_ => initTables())
                .then(_ => validateTables())
                .catch(error => logError('Something went wrong', error))
```

Comment: hey thank you so much! this worked, however i had to add the following line into user addresses : `userId :    {type:DataTypes.INTEGER,   allowNull:false, references: {model: 'user', key: 'id',},}` . I read somewhere that these associations are necessary to create the foreign key. i wish to name it `user_id` though, and not `userId` . so is that possible? i tried changing the name in this constraint, but that didn't worked

Comment: You just need to indicate `foreignKey: 'user_id'` in the association options.